# dotnet new generates a .csproj file instead of project.json

Tags: macos, .net-core

I am following this documentation https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos on how to run .NET Core on mac. I have successfully installed the `dotnet` command and all but when I try to create a new project using `dotnet new`, it generates a `.csproj` file as opposed to `project.json` as described. This doesn't allow me to go on to run `dotnet restore` or `dotnet run` to run this new project. I don't know what I'm missing out here. Kindly assist.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't install some version directly from the lastest version of the repository? What does `dotnet --version` return?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around this. I created a `project.json` file and put the necessary parameters in it. In this case,

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0"
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Then `dotnet restore` works there on.
Cheers!